# Invoking nested function from other class

Tags: react-native

kIn react Native APP, The top level function Home is defined in Home.js and with this is a method getUser,as follows:

```
const Home = ({navigation}) => {
      const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
      const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
      const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    
       const getUsers = (count) => {
```

...
}

In File B.js I do import {Home} from Home.js. I want to invoke getUsers from B.js with some parameters, 'export' is not allowed before 'const getUsers' because its nested function. How do I do invoke getUsers.